# Mixed List in Realm

Tags: swift, realm

If you want to define a `List` (an array) in realm, you something like this:

```
var products = List<Product>()
```

But how do I define a `List` which can contain a mixture of object types? The equivalent of an AnyObject array in Swift? I've tried:

```
var recentItems = List<AnyObject>()
```

and

```
var recentItems = List<Object>()
```

.. but these don't seem to work. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't currently possible. [This comment](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1109#issuecomment-143834756) on the Realm Cocoa Github issue tracker explains why (Realm only supports subclassing polymorphism to a minimal degree), and contains a couple of potential workarounds.